# How to use plt.colorbar() and cmap jet python

Tags: python, colorbar

I have the followin code, I looked everywhere but don't seem to be able to figure out how to change the color bar to the cmap jet (preferable to the list of colors in the code)
[current plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mfno9.png)

```
# bilinear interpolation #
f=interpolate.interp2d(x,x,y_lijst,kind='linear')
xnew = search_coord
ynew = search_coord
znew=f(xnew,ynew)
#print znew
#print matrix

# change color colorbar #
colors = [(0.00, 0.00, 1.00),(0.00, 0.28, 0.96),(0.00, 0.54, 0.84),(0.00,0.76, 0.65),(0.00, 0.91, 0.41),(0.00, 0.99, 0.14),(0.14, 0.99, 0.00),(0.41 ,0.91, 0.00),(0.65, 0.76, 0.00),(0.84, 0.54, 0.00),(0.96, 0.28, 0.00),(1.00, 0.00, 0.00)]


fig=plt.figure()
plt.imshow(znew)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

Comment: There is a keyword `cmap` for the imshow function. For example: `plt.imshow(znew, cmap="Blues")`. See [this link](https://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html) for the various colormaps and code example.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: And [don't use jet if possible, use viridis](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xAoljeRJ3lU). I.e. leave the default. It's good for your data.